# Не показывается нотификация пользователю

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notification, androidx

Есть приложение, которое отображает пользователю некое уведомление. Нотификация показывается лишь по нажатию на кнопку. Однако, при выполнении даного условия ничего не происходит

Код активити:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL_ID = "channel_one"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button_start_notification.setOnClickListener {
            sendNotification()
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification() {
        val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_layout)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.content_title))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_android)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Test Notification",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
                description = "This notification is for test"
            }
            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(0, notification)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно надо сначала создавать канал, а потом уже само уведомление.

Comment: Делал, но не помогло. Пересмотрел много туториалов по этой теме, все именно так и сделано, как в видео, но ничего не работает.

Comment: Очень странно. А если ID не 0 сделать?

Comment: Все тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в этой части кода:

```
.setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
.setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
```

Скорее всего, кастомизация нотификаций происходит инным путем. Как именно, не известно. Поэтому для работы уведомления указаные строчки я убрал и все начало работать, как нужно.